# how to dynamically build a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to dynamically build a dictionary in python. based upon a set of shows that has one dimension.

this is what i have currently do when looping through the entries

```
class Show(object):
    def __init__(self, json_data):
        self.name = json_data.get("abstract_name")
        self.id = json_data.get("abstract_key")
        self.station = json_data.get("station")
        self.first_letter = json_data.get("first_letter")


    def to_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__


 shows = {} 
 for entry in json.get("material"):
        show = Show(entry)
        first_letter = show.first_letter

        if shows.get(first_letter, None) is None:
            shows.update(first_letter, {})

        if shows.get(first_letter).get(show.id, None) is None:
            shows.get(first_letter).update(show.id, {})

        shows.get(first_letter).get(show.id).update(show.to_dict())
```

What i want to do is create the indexes where it is empty. But i can't seem to find a way to do this

Comment: are we supposed to guess what `Show` is and how it's implemented ?

Comment: Sorry didn't know that was of use

Comment: Ok the definition of `shows` is also missing but I assume this is a dict.

Comment: Added the definition of `shows` as a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not using `dict.update()` the right way. `dict.update()` expects either:

1/ a dict (or dict-like) object

```
d.update({"foo":"bar"})
```

2/ a sequence (list or any iterable) of `(key, value)` pairs

```
d.update([("foo", "bar")])
```

3/ keyword args

```
d.update(foo="bar")
```

Note that all those three examples could be written much more simply as

```
d["foo"] = "bar"
```

`dict.update()` is mostly useful if you want to set many keys at once and/or already have another dict or a sequence of key,value pairs.

Also, you don't have to `.get()` a key to test if it's already set, you can test for containment with `key in yourdict` (negating it with `key not in yourdict`) ie:

```
if first_letter not in shows:
    shows[first_letter] = {}
```

But in your case, the simplest solution is to [use a `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# we want a defaultdict of defauldicts of dicts,
# so we need a custom factory function
def defaultdict_of_dicts():
    return defaultdict(dict)

shows = defaultdict(defaultdict_of_dicts)

for entry in json.get("material"):
    show = Show(entry)
    shows[show.first_letter][show.id].update(show.to_dict())
```

As a last note: your `show.to_dict()` method may have unwanted side effects:

```
>>> s = Show({"abstract_name":"name", "abstract_key": "key", "station":"station", "first_letter":"first_letter"}) 
>>> s.first_letter
'first_letter'
>>> d = s.to_dict()
>>> d
{'first_letter': 'first_letter', 'station': 'station', 'name': 'name', 'id': 'key'}
>>> d["first_letter"] = "gotcha"
>>> s.first_letter
'gotcha'
>>>
```

It would be safer to implement `to_dict()` as `return self.__dict__.copy()` (well, might not be that important in this exact example, but better safe than sorry...)